# In spree admin , taxons not loading says "searching"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, spree

In my ruby application with spree at its backend , i am not able to add taxons to a product.

Its showing loading failed... [image]

[image]

```
Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 
422 (Unprocessable Entity)
:3000/api/taxons?per_page=50&page=1&without_children=true&q%5Bname_cont%5D=&token=477cdac328120d8a3dcb804358ec4535091366faf9e988f3&_=1517890528589
```

I have tried regenerating the API key.But didn't solve the issue.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: 422 (Unprocessable Entity) is an indication that the data you sent to the server is malformed, the last bit of your query string looks suspicious to me, I'm not sure if the server can process that, in any case check the format of the data

Comment: @Subash, similar type of autosuggest is there for option types , which is working fine. The data format over there is : `http://192.168.0.106:3000/api/option_types?
 q%5Bname_cont%5D=s&token=477cdac328120d8a3dcb804358ec4535091366faf9e988f3&_=1517892848246` .

Comment: have you tried debugging with minimum parameters for success and try adding request params in url to check which key is responsible

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. The issue arised due to 'will_paginate' gem.
By replacing the config/initializers/will_paginate.rb

```
 if defined?(WillPaginate)
  module WillPaginate
  module ActiveRecord
   module RelationMethods
   def per_page(num)
    if (n = num.to_i) <= 0
      self
     else
      limit(n).offset(offset_value / limit_value * n)
    end
   end

def total_pages
  (total_count.to_f / limit_value).ceil
end

alias_method :per, :per_page
alias_method :num_pages, :total_pages
alias_method :total_count, :total_entries
  end
 end
```

end
  end`